What is this rat/animal kids movie?
The only things I remember about this movie is, one... 

It features a cartoon rat in 3D style
Not live action and is a kids movie
Humans are in it, I think
The bad guy is a lion
Another side character is a skunk.

So if you know what the movie is, please tell me. It is probably an old one and probably not Disney.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year of release? And anything about the plot, or specific scenes?

When you say "3D" you mean "CGI", right? Because "an old one" to me would be pre-CGI. CGI pretty much means it's from the last 20 years.

I'm pretty sure not CGI. I know that the skunk finishes off the lion by using his spray.

Although it might've been CGI.

@Mitchell computer / 3D / CGI animation are used interchangably by most people. do you know of another film that reminds you of this films visual style?

How sure are you that the lion was bad and the rat was good? The TV series King Leonardo and His Short Subjects was about a lion and a skunk teaming up against a rat. Definitely not "3D" though.

Without any plot info, I can't be sure, but you might mean "Stuart Little 3: Call of the Wild"
http://imdb.com/rg/an_share/title/title/tt0472602/
There is a mouse (not rat), humans,and the skunk sprays a mountain lion(?)

